Replaced fuel pump but truck still won't start
2003 Ford F150 V8 5.4L Triton - I replaced my fuel pump. The injectors are getting fuel, but my fuel pump turns on and won't stop. The truck will turnover but not start. I'm not sure if it's the fuel pressure regulator or what the issue is.

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! If you put a fuel pressure gauge on there, it should tell you if you're getting the correct fuel pressure.

There are several ways of troubleshooting EFI systems; removing spark plugs after failed starting to see if fuel is reaching cylinders (wet raw fuel), spark test, and spraying starting fluid into the throttle body. Injector operate with fuel pressure but require injectors signals. Spark is generated from ecm signals. Both needed to ignite in each cylinder. Fuel being sprayed or not? Spark generated or not?  Central to both failing; crank sensor.

It seems your issue might be related to the fuel pressure regulator or the fuel pump control system. If the fuel pump runs continuously, the regulator could be faulty, failing to provide the correct pressure to the injectors or properly managing the return flow of fuel. It’s recommended to measure the fuel system’s pressure using a fuel pressure gauge. If the pressure is too high or too low, the regulator likely needs to be replaced.
Additionally, checking the fuel pump relay and fuel system wiring is crucial. The relay might be stuck, causing the pump to stay on continuously. Replacing the relay or inspecting the related electrical circuits can resolve this issue. If everything appears to be functioning correctly and the problem persists, the issue might lie within the ignition system or sensors such as the crankshaft or camshaft position sensors, which could prevent the engine from starting. At this point, using an OBD-II scanner to check for error codes could provide valuable insights into the root cause of the issue.

AI generated answers are not allowed on this site.
